# Why `MediaRecorder`'s `onInfoListener` is not called in below code when max file size is reached

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, video-recording

I'm recording video with in my Android app. but want to display message when max file size reached. I don't understand why `MediaRecorder`'s `onInfoListener` is not called in below code when max file size is reached an file is saved?

```
final Context activity=this.getBaseContext();

mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {

    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(what==MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED)
         Toast.makeText(activity, "There is no more space available. Video recording is stopped now.",2000).show();

    }
});

// getBytesAvailable() returns bytes available on sdcard
mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(getBytesAvailable());

mediaRecorder.prepare();

mediaRecorder.start();
```

Comment: Have you tried a smaller value than what is returned getBytesAvailable()?  It seems that using up all of the space on the sdcard could cause other issues.

Comment: In my code I actually tried to set max file size 100kb less than what is available, made no difference

Comment: Did you find the solution?